# Type of expression is ambiguous without more contextにはどうすればいいのか

Tags: swift

FirebaseでGoogle認証をしたく、[公式ドキュメント](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start?hl=ja)を参考にしながら進めていたのですが、"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" と表示されて躓いています。どのようにすれば対処できるでしょうか。ご教示いただきたいです。

[image: スクショ]

### コード

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseAuth


@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        let ud = UserDefaults.standard
        let firstLunchKey = "firstLunch"
        let firstLunch = [firstLunchKey: true]
        ud.register(defaults: firstLunch)
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
    }


}
```

loginViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseAuth


class loginViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapSoginButton(_ sender: Any) {
        auth()
    }
    
    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    
    private func auth() {
        guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
        let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
        
//この下の一行に出てます
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: self) { [unowned self] user, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("GIDSignInError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let authentication = user?.authentication,
                  let idToken = authentication.idToken else { return }
            
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
            self.login(credential: credential)
        }
    }
    
    private func login(credential: AuthCredential) {
        print("ログイン完了")
    }

}
```